# Keep UI data when navigating between views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

In my test project I have a ViewController and a TableViewController controller embedded in a Navigation Controller. The ViewController is the main view, and the user can navigate to the TableViewController and then return back to the ViewController.

I am using a 'push' segue when going from ViewContoller>TableViewController, and the TableViewController is dismissed using `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` when the user wishes to go back to ViewController.

In ViewController, I have a button that changes the text on a label:

```
-(IBAction)onButtonPress:(id)sender {
      _myLabel.text = @"New Label Text";
}
```

When navigating to TableView, and then back to ViewController, **the change in the _myLabel.text has been lost and the original text is restored**. What is the best way to ensure UI data is retained when navigating between views? I might only have one label in this project, but at some point I will have many UI elements, for example, WebViews that need to keep a page loaded when the user navigates away and then comes back.

What would you suggest is the best method to implementing this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use Block or delegate & Protocol for it.

Comment: But once UI loaded its state never changes until you change them. If i am wrong then anyone might correct it.

Comment: as @Prince Stated is right, if the Viewcontrolelr is the rootViewController(TableVC is child or presented as different) but the root ViewController's data should remain.

Comment: You might be deal with at ViewDidLoad or DidAppear, Check that.

Comment: Is it possible that the Navigation Controller becomes the root instead of the view controller?

I just made a test project again, exactly the same as above, except I didn't use a Navigation Controller and I used the 'modal' setting when navigating to the second view. This time, data is retained in the label after the navigation (it works perfectly).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, View is your data representation, any data is your Model. So you may store Model with its entities and values. Your controllers manage data to represent it on View or to change Model according to user actions in View.

So add some Model-object for storing `_myLabel.text`. And use this object for both controllers in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove setting the text from the `ViewWillAppear` or `ViewDidAppear` method, put it in `ViewDidLoad`.